# Inserting Items into a List<T> using random index

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(30);

list.Insert(1, "string 1");
list.Insert(10, "string 10");
list.Insert(5, "string 5");
```

The run-time is crashing on sting 10 with exception **Index must be within the bounds of the List**

What I can't understand is that I have defined a list with 30 items, so why does this crash and what is the point of defining the 30 if I can't add an items in such way?

Comment: Look at the Count property after the list is created.  What does it say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list is still empty when initialized. The parameter '30' means it will simply have the capacity of 30 items.

If you insist on using a list instead of an array, you must first add 30 items and then you can set them with their appropriate index.

The easiest way to do this would be:

```
List<string> list = new string[30].ToList();

list[1] = "string 1";
list[10] = "string 10";
list[5] = "string 5";
```

Also note that when you're using `Insert`, it will basically `Add` the item to a certain index, so the number of items in the list will grow.

Comment: I wonder why did you edit your answer and remove the Enumerable.Range(0, blobItems.Count).Select(x => (string)null).ToList()

Comment: @RegisteredUser I thought of that other way of doing it and believed it was more readable.

Comment: He could also make the list with `new List<string>(new string[30])` I think. But why not simply use an array?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Also good way of doing this. Perhaps better, even! I agree with you completely, but the question was for how to do it with a list, so I suppose he's got his reasons.

Comment: Thanks Jeppe! This is the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(30);
```

Initializes the `list` to a *capacity* of 30 items. It doesn't create 30 items.

The list is *empty* at this time. You need to first *add* 30 items, then you can `Insert` randomly, though you can sort these items to a random order, as described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10567180/1583) by [ivowiblo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1070247/ivowiblo).

See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10567167/1583) by [Yorye Nathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1282539/yorye-nathan) for an approach to initialize a list with 30 items (using LINQ).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx). As you can see the insert method uses the *count* variable of the list an not the *capacity*. This means that you can insert elements in positions up to the current count of the list, which is the effective number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

You **reserved** memory for 30 elements, but  actually your list is empty **before first insert**, so,  after inserting one element there is no position 10 in your list.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

list.Add("string 1");
list.Add("string 10");
list.Add("string 5");
var randomOrder = list.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid());
```

Comment: Not sure what this does? Why the GUID?

Comment: It will give you a list with the items in random order.

Comment: Right, what about a ascending order  string 1,string 5,string 10?

Comment: Just use an array instead of a list...

Comment: ...and remove the "random" from the title :)

Comment: @ivowiblo That's not a good way to shuffle a list.  First off, it's important for the comparator for a list to be determinate in deciding whether an item is larger than another (it can't be larger at one time and smaller after a second call).  Next, [a guid is not a good method of generating random numbers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/04/30/guid-guide-part-two.aspx).

Comment: Ok, but it does the job and gives an idea of how to solve the issue.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.  He wants a random index, as it says in the title.